# Undefined Symbols for architecture arm64 Stripe Ios build in Ionic from xcode

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3, stripe-payments

I am building a ios ionic app and running from xcode . I am getting the following error:

[image: Error From Xcode Build]

Iam using cordova-plugin-stripe plugin for this.

Please check with this

Comment: xcode version 7

Comment: any help on this